# Let $A, B$ be closed in $\mathbb{R}.$ Show that the product $A \times B$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A, B$ be closed in $\mathbb{R}.$ Show that the product $A \times B$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $x=(x_A,x_B) \in (A\times B)^c$ such that $x_A \in A^c$ and $x_B \in B^c$. What I wanted to show was that since $A$ and $B$ are closed, then there is an open neighborhoods $B(x_A,r) \subset A^c$ and $B(x_B,r') \subset B^c$ for all $r,r' >0$. This would imply that $x \in B(x_A,r) \times B(x_B,r')$ so  $B(x_A,r) \times B(x_B,r')$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and since $x \in (A\times B)^c$ we would have that $(A \times B)$ is closed since it's complement is open. This doesn't seem to be correct though since $(A\times B)^c \ne A^c \times B^c$ so I wouldn't neccessarily have that $x_A \in A^c$ and $x_B \in B^c$?

Comment: Wouldn't it easier to use the sequential characterization of closedness?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x,y) \notin A \times B$. There are twe possibilities:

a) $x \notin A$

b) $y \notin B$.

Suppose  $x \notin A$. There exists $r >0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset A^{c}$. Verify that $B((x,y),r) \subset (A \times B)^{c}$.

Case b) is similar.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that typically $(A\times B)^c\neq A^c\times B^c$. But $(x_A,x_B)\in (A\times B)^c$ implies that $x_A\in A^c$ **or** $x_B\in B^c$. WLOG assume that $x_A\in A^c$. Then $(x_A,x_B)\in A^c\times \mathbb{R}$ which is an open neighbourhood of $(x_A,x_B)$ that doesn't intersect $A\times B$. By the arbitrary choice of $(x_A,x_B)$ we conclude that $(A\times B)^c$ is open.

Note that this approach can be easily generalized to any topological space product $X\times Y$, not only $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

With sequences: let $((x_n,y_n))$ be a convergent sequence in $A \times B$ with limit $(x,y)$.

Then $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$. Since $A$ and $B$ are closed , we have $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, thus $(x,y) \in A \times B$.